# live streaming Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, video-streaming, live, flash-media-server

I have been working on a Flex application that sends a feed from my webcam to the Flash Media server. The application connects to the server fine but for some reason the camera is not sending anything to the Media Server. I am pretty sure that the answer to my question is really simple but I need another set of eyes to llok at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong.
Any help would be greatly!! GREATLY.. appreciated. I need to keep the little bit of hair I have left!
here is the function... thanks again.

```
private function Publisher():void{

            var camera1:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
            var video:Video = new Video(285, 254);
            if (camera1)
            {
                video.attachCamera(camera1);
                VideoDisplay1.addChild(video);
                camera1.addEventListener(ActivityEvent.ACTIVITY, camera_activity);
                camera1.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, camera_status);
            }

            var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
            nc.connect("rtmp://po9nawn4.rtmphost.com/Application");
            nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);

            function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
                switch (event.info.code) {
                    case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                        var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
                        ns.attachCamera(camera1);
                        ns.publish("test", "live");
                        break;
                    case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
                        trace("Unable to locate video: ");
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Merged your unregistered account into the registered one.

Comment: I just saw it. I was not able to connect to the internet for the last 3-4 days. I will try it tonight and let you know. I am anxious to try it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hello ww0z0k, I tried the function but for some reason that I do not know yet it is not detecting the camera :-( there is nothing else that is wrong with it so I figured that if I can get it working we will be good to go! :-) BTW I am kind of new to this concept but.. do you know what the best way to import a package in FLEX is? (I had to cut the functions from what you posted and past them into my code)

Answer (score 0):

try moving `netStatusHandler` outside `Publisher`
and btw are you connecting to the default FMS app? does fms_adminConsole.swf show your client?
**upd :**

```
package  {
/**
 * ...
 * @author www0z0k
 */
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    [SWF(width='400', height='300', frameRate='30')]
    public class NewClass extends Sprite {
    private var vid:Video;
    private var nc:NetConnection;
    private var ns:NetStream;
    private var baseUrl:String = 'rtmp://192.168.1.100/live';
    private var appUrl:String = 'stream1';
    private var cam:Camera;
    public function NewClass() {
        vid = new Video();
        addChild(vid);
        cam = Camera.getCamera();
        vid.attachCamera(cam);
        nc = new NetConnection();
        nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onStatus);
        nc.connect(baseUrl);
    }

    private function onStatus(e:NetStatusEvent):void {
            switch (e.info.code) {
            case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                ns = new NetStream(nc, NetStream.CONNECT_TO_FMS);
                ns.attachCamera(cam);
                ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onStatus);
                ns.publish(appUrl, 'live');
                break;
             }
      }
  }
}
```

works perfect on my dev fms

Comment: Thank you so much 0z0k for your reply.
I tried moving the net StatusHandler function outside of Publisher but I am getting an error saying that the "NetConnection object must be connected" ERROE#:2126
I tried multiple way to fox it but with no success so I put it back where it was.
I crerated a FMS App I just miodified the name in the rtmp link for posting on the forum.
the adminConsole shows me the name of the stream I am publishing though.

Comment: try `var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc, NetStream.CONNECT_TO_FMS);`

Comment: I just added it to the code and nothing is happening. It was a good idea though to add this argument to the constructor NetStream constructor. Whaty is mind boggling is that I created the same application in Flash (a very watered down version of my Flex application) and it works. But when I go back to flex, nothing happens.